# Node.js imagemagick Error: Too many pages in Page tree. while converting pdf to png

Tags: javascript, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

I have some trouble while converting some pdfs to png thumbnail.

```js
const outputStream = gm(Buffer.from(path, 'base64'))
        .selectFrame(0)
        .noProfile()
        .quality(60)
        .density(200)
        .background('white')
        .resize(600, 600)
        .setFormat('png');
```

[Then I just got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7ucs.png)

[Here you can see those pdfs](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wmr43uxuewgrbid/AADNx3xQvXrmuSarsPz26H9sa?dl=0)

Is there any way to fix this error or another way to get pdf thumbnail?

Comment: These pdfs contain forms, maybe after deleting forms it will work...

Answer (score 1):

**Flag -flatten solved my problem :)**

> In some file formats (e.g. Photoshop's PSD) complex images may be represented by "layers" (independent images) which must be composited in order to obtain the final rendition. The -flatten option accomplishes this composition. The sequence of images is replaced by a single image created by compositing each image in turn, while respecting composition operators and page offsets. While -flatten is immediately useful for eliminating layers, it is also useful as a general-purpose composition tool.

So I just generate flatten pdf and then convert it to image

Hope it will help somebody

```
const flattenPDFStream = gm(Buffer.from(path, 'base64'))
  .define('pdf:use-cropbox=true')
  .selectFrame(0)
  .flatten();

const flattenPDF = await gmToBuffer(flattenPDFStream);
const outputStream = gm(flattenPDF)
  .selectFrame(0)
  .noProfile()
  .quality(90)
  .background('white')
  .resize(400, 400)
  .setFormat('png');
```

GM to buffer function:

```
function gmToBuffer(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    data.stream((err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) { return reject(err); }
      const chunks = [];
      stdout.on('data', chunk => {
        // Not best solution, but i need to control error message will not appear in pdf
        if (!chunk.includes('Error')) {
          chunks.push(chunk);
        } else {
          console.log(chunk.toString());
        }
      });
      // these are 'once' because they can and do fire multiple times for multiple errors,
      // but this is a promise so you'll have to deal with them one at a time
      stdout.once('end', () => { resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)); });
      stderr.once('data', data => { reject(String(data)); });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Maybe creating pdf is unnecessary, but at least it works